# Can directed set be finite?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, nets

Can we have directed sets to be finite sets?

How do we define nets on such sets?

How do we define clustering and convergence of such nets?

Comment: Of course there are finite directed sets. For example finite subsets of $\mathbb N$. Or take a rooted tree and declare $a\le b$ if the path from $a$ to the root passes $b$. - Now investigate how the definitions of net, clustering, convergence apply to such a directed set; the unique maximum of the set plays a crucial role.

Comment: Note that any two elements of a directed set must have a shared successor, but it needn't be a *strict* successor.

Answer (score 10):

Note that in a directed set every finite subset has an upper bound. If the directed set itself is finite, then it must have a maximum (why?). Therefore the limit of such net is the element associated with the maximum index.

Convergence is trivial in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The empty set $\emptyset$ is directed (if empty set is allowed). A non-empty directed set is $(\{1\},1\le1)$. If a net $\Phi$ over a finite directed set $I$ converges to $x$, then for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is an $\alpha\in I$ such that for all $\beta\ge\alpha$ we have $\Phi_\beta\in U$. If one defines the tail $T_\alpha$ as the set of all $\Phi_\beta$ with $\beta\ge\alpha$, then this means that each $U$ around $x$ contains a tail. One also says *The net $\Phi$ is eventually in $U$*, since by the common upper bound in a directed set, each "line" in $I$ (which you should think of as a sequence $\gamma\le\gamma_1\le\gamma_2\le...$) eventually meets the tail $T_\alpha$.

Note that a finite directed set $I$ has a greatest element $m$ (As Asaf wrote, each finite subset of a directed set has an upper bound), but if your $(I,\le)$ is not a poset, then $m$ may not be unique. However, if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are both greatest elements, then they are *equivalent* ($m_1\le m_2$ and $m_2\le m_1$), and equivalent elements have always the same tails. The tail $T_m$ is then precisely the set $\{\Phi_m\mid m\text{ is a greatest element of }I\}$, call it $M$.
Now a net $\Phi$ over $I$ converges to $x$ if and only if $\Phi$ is eventually in each neighborhood of $x$, which means that each open $U$ around $x$ contains $M$.

We can summarize: A net $\Phi$ over a finite directed set $I$

- converges to $x$ if $M$ is in every neighborhood of $x$,
- has $\overline M$ as the set of cluster points.

In a $T_1$-space we can say more: The cluster points are $M$ itself, while the limit of $\Phi$ only exists if $M$ is a singleton.
Here is an example of finite net with limits and cluster points which are not limits: Let $X=\Bbb N$ with the topology generated by the sets $\{1,2,...,n\},\ n\in\Bbb N$. Let $I=(\{a,b\},\le)$, where $a<b$ and $b<a$ and $\Phi_a=2, \Phi_b=5$. Now each point $\ge5$ is a limit while each number except $1$ is a cluster point of $\Phi$. any net $\Phi$ converges to any number larger than the maximal value of $\Phi$.